# weblogic jmx tomcata php/java bridge and getting t3 protocol working

Tags: java, php, weblogic

I have PHP and the PHP/Java bridge set up on Windows and Tomcat 7.0. All is OK there.

However, I am trying to write a php file with java calls to connect to my Weblogic server installed on my Windows 7 machine to play around with adding/deleting users/groups etc.

This is what I followed: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jmx/accessWLS.html I also looked at this one http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2009/10/11/creating-users-in-weblogic-server-embedded-ldap-programatically/ (but for the second one I get an error on the java:comp/env/jmx/runtime  line)

However, I cannot get my set up to recognize "t3" protocols to connect to my weblogic. the weird thing is I can connect via a t3 protocol using jython in a separate standalone script and to the console that way.

There is a section in first link above to make sure that wljmxclient.jar is added to the classpath. I set up a classpath to add that. I even use PHP to exec Weblogic's setWLSenv.cmd right before the connection to my Weblogic server is made to set my classpath . . . it shows the jar file in question being added. Still won't work. I then copied the jar file to the JavaBirde/WEB-INF/lib folder. Still wont' work.

I did try IIOP protocol but then I started down an new path of errors where "not bound in this context" was indicated. I tried switching between the 3 Mservers mentioned in the Oracle doc link above. No luck there either.

I see that others have run into this "t3 protocol not supported" message but I don't see any solutions.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

require_once("java/Java.inc");

$output=exec("C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\bin\setWLSenv.cmd");

$protocol = "t3";
$hostname = "localhost";
$port="7001";
$jndiroot="/jndi/";
$mserver="weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
$united = $jndiroot.$mserver;
$serviceURL = new java("javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL",$protocol, $hostname, $port,$united);

$h = new java("java.util.Hashtable");
$h->put("javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL", "myUID");
$h->put("javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS", "myPWD");
$h->put("javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES",
         "weblogic.management.remote");

$connector = new java("javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory");

$connector->connect($serviceURL,$h);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I FINALLY connected to my Weblogic:

1) I installed Tomcat 7.0 zip file instead of the installer and set it up manually. In my

```
setenv.bat file it looks like:
set CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.34
set CATALINA_BASE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.34
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09
set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\jre
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\lib
set CLASSPATH=.;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\wljmxclient.jar

exit /b 0
```

2) I enabled IIOP protocol in weblogic through the weblogic console and added a userid/password which I used in num 3 for the userID/password

3) My php script on Tomcat 7 with the PHP/Java Bridge (not the JMXServerURL . . . nowhere did I find that you had to use "rmi" as the protocol")

```
$serviceURL = new java("javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL","rmi","localhost","7001","/jndi/iiop://localhost:7001/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit");

//"service:jmx:iiop://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.edit");

$env = new java("java.util.Hashtable");
$env->put("javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES","weblogic.management.remote");
$env->put("javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL", "myuserID");
$env->put("javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS", "mypassword");

$jmxCon = java("javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory")->newJMXConnector($serviceURL, $env);
$jmxCon->connect();
$connection = $jmxCon->getMBeanServerConnection();

$mbeans = $connection->queryNames(null,null);

foreach($mbeans as $key=>$value) {
echo $key. "=". $value;
}
```

It connected and printed out all the mbeans for my admin server and my two managed servers that I created for testing.